# What are the differences between restrict, __restrict, and _restrict_ keywords in C++?

Tags: c++, restrict-qualifier

There are three entities named around `restrict` for which I wonder if there is any clear or subtle distinction:

- [`restrict` (type qualifier in C)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict)
- [`__restrict__` (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html)
- [`__restrict` (MSVC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extension-restrict?view=vs-2019)

Are these entities virtually always interchangeable in terms of their functionality?

Comment: `restrict` is not part of C++. Some compilers provide equivalent as extension.

Comment: It's not really needed in C++, since (other than `char*`) everything is pretty much `restrict` assumed.

Comment: @Eljay: strict aliasing rule (C and C++) only prevents aliasing between "different" types (with indeed `char*` exception). For same type, aliasing might/does occur. So `restrict` would be useful but it is dangerous (breaking contract lead to UB)...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict